# Golang run on Windows without deal with the Firewall

Tags: go, windows-firewall

I'm working on a Rest API with Go, but everytime I try to run my application with

```
go run main.go
```

the Windows Firewall tells me that has blocked some features of my app. I would like to know if there's some way to make my executions without have to *Accept* everytime.

Comment: If by any chance the action we're talking about is starting an HTTP(s) server, then while you develop, use localhost, e.g. instead of `":8080"`, use `"localhost:8080"`. That is not a restricted action.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hi I had the same problem:
Try that:

1. Go to **Windows Defender Firewall**, in Left side menu you saw **Inbound Rules** click there, then Right Side menu you will see **New Rule...** click.
2. *Choose Port* opened from window -> **Next**
   *Select TCP*, then *define which ports you want* I choose 8080 click **Next** again, Choose *Allow the connection* **Next**, Check All **Next**, *Give any Name* Goland or anything you want and press **Finish**. Thats it

Answer (score 95):

Change

```golang
http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
```

to

```golang
http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:3000", r)
```

Comment: `http.ListenAndServe("localhost:3000", r)` worked for me too

Comment: don't forget to set it back to http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r) when you deploy it to your production server guys. except you use reverse proxy for it, you would not be able to access it remotely. got me a headache for few hours before I realize that this is the cause :)

Comment: This works, but if you’re on windows, I’d recommend the solution from Ismayil - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65393403/9808334

Comment: @JackySupit Thank you for your important hint. You could also give this information via a command-line flag: go run ./cmd/web -addr="localhost:9090"

Answer (score 23):

If you are calling `go run main.go` the following is happening:

- your program is compiled inside a temporary folder
- the compiled binary is executed

But the temporary folder is just for one execution. So the next time when you run your program via `go run` another folder is used.

The Windows firewall always gives you the path your server has and if you remember the paths after each time you will see that there is always a different path.

The Windows firewall is configured so that it remembers the path of each program. So when the path is changed you will always need to confirm that the *new* path is allowed to run on that port.

To fix this you should compile your server. Just run `go build` and execute the binaries inside your project folder. Then you will just have to accept once.

Comment: this is a good explanation of why this is actually happening but I think @the Mage has a better solution of fixing the issue aside from just build the the program.

Answer (score 3):

this work for me

```
go build main.go && .\main.exe
```

and run using makefile

Answer (score 1):

based on @**apxp** answer

in **windows cli** this works for me

**go build main.go && main.exe**

Answer (score 0):

I think @apxp's answer is the complete explanation of the situation; some time after ask this question I found a way to run my application with:

```
go build -o ejecutable.exe ; if($?)  { .\ejecutable.exe }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your Windows Firewall notification settings:

`Control Panel -> Windows Defender Firewall -> Change notification settings`

Uncheck the option for **Notify me when Windows Defender Firewall blocks a new app** to prevent it from showing the popup.

Comment: This change will silence the firewall, so it will be rejecting all subsequent attempts to open the port, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CompileDaemon](https://github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon) to auto re-build your project on file changes, because it runs a build anyway, you'll only have to accept once. Plus, your project will re-build automatically!

Install:

```sh
go get https://github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
```

Example usage:

```sh
# Assuming your project looks like and you're in your project working dir
# hello/
#   hello.go

# Rebuild on .go file edits and run the hello command after
CompileDaemon -command="./hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

The WSL run under VM, so you have to execute **ifconfig**

You will see your IP in the section (eth0:) inet x.x.x.x

This x.x.x.x is the IP you have to put in your browser.